# python - comparing list to csv

Tags: python

I have this .csv:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
247,19,1.0,2016-01-01 14:11:21,MP
247,3,1.0,2016-01-01 14:23:43,MP
247,12,1.0,2016-01-01 15:32:16,MP
402,3,1.0,2016-01-01 12:11:15,?
583,12,1.0,2016-01-01 02:33:57,?
769,16,1.0,2016-01-01 03:12:24,?
769,4,1.0,2016-01-01 03:22:29,?
.....
```

I need to take col2 values for each col1 unique element and make a new .csv like this:

```
expected output:
19,3,12
3
12
16,4
...
```

That is, I want to output numbers until a non-unique value is seen, at which point I will start a new line and continue to output numbers.

I read the .csv in that way and removed duplicate from the list:

```
import pandas as pd
colnames = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']
df = pd.read_csv('sorted.csv', names=colnames)
list1 = df.col1.tolist()
list2 = list(set(list1 ))
```

now things are getting hard for me, I'm newbie in python, my idea was to compare each element in list2 with each row in df writing col2 elements in a new .csv, could you help me please?

Comment: what is your expected output of the df you wan to write to csv?

Comment: You only need the first and second item from each line. Store them in a more useful data structure. Then iterate over that to generate the output.

Comment: If your intended output should be all column 2 values for a certain value of column 1, why are removing duplicates values of column 1? Wouldn't this result in only one value of column 2 corresponding to a value in column 1? Please clarify your intended result so we could address this.

Comment: Please provide an example output and I'll build a possible answer

Comment: the example output is in the first post: "I need to take col2 values for each col1 unique element and make a new .csv like this:", so I just need a .csv file with that sequences, each row should be the sequence for a single value in col1

Comment: @Nivii1406 I removed duplicates because my idea was to check each value of the list without duplicates  with the csv file to get col2 values

Comment: don't drop duplicates. instead create a new list that you append and check before printing things out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Example in python3

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
x = pd.read_csv('input.txt')
y = x[['col1','col2']]
with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  y.groupby(['col1']).agg(lambda x: writer.writerow(list(x.values)))
```

Maybe, you can try this. Don't store the whole output in a list or any Data Structure(memory issue). Write to file as you read and aggregate.(the reading should also be optimized to get an iterator if possible rather than loading the whole thing at once from input file.

Comment: this is almost perfect! is there any way to remove empty rows in the file? actually I have got an empty row between rows with elements

Comment: Is something like df.dropna (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: @Nivii1406 seems that but it's not working, I get this error: 
"ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 9, saw 4
in line 9"     I have 4 numbers in the row

Comment: I've solved by adding ' , newline='' ' after "w" in with open, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by grouping your data then applying a `set` function as the aggregation.

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(set).apply(list)
```

The `apply(set)` function creates a set of all distinct `col2` elements for each `col1` value then the `apply(list)` function converts the set into a list.

Comment: Hi ,      `import pandas as pd
colnames = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']
df = pd.read_csv('sorted.csv', names=colnames)

for value in df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(set).apply(list):

    print ",".join(map(str,value))
` prints the following 19,3,12
3
12
4,16
col2  even the header line is included in the output

Comment: @AbinayaDevarajan- are the headers included in your `sorted.csv` file?  That seems to be the case.  You are setting the `names` parameter in `read_csv` which will by default set `header=None`, which will treat the first row with the header information as a row in the data.

Answer (score 0):

you need to track your duplicates.  The most simple (as in easy to understand, but sacrificing some efficiencies) way is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
colnames = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']
df = pd.read_csv('sorted.csv', names=colnames)

list1 = df.col2.tolist()
dup_tracker = []
for x in list1:
    if x in dup_tracker: file_out_helper('\n')
    file_out_helper(str(x) + ', ')
    dup_tracker.append(x)

def file_out_helper(m_str):
    tgtfile = 'my_target_file.csv'
    with open(tgtfile,'a') as f: f.write(m_str)
```